# Sendmail attach all files in directory

Tags: sendmail

I want to send mail and attach all files in directory.
Below doesn't work

```
sendMail -a | find . -name '*.*'
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a **tarball** of the directory first:

```
tar -cvf attachments.tar.gz <directory>
```

---

Then send **that** file:

```
uuencode /path/attachments.tar.gz | sendmail -s "subject" user@domain
```

Comment: I agree with the above answer. You're piping it backwards. You want to get the collection of files (or one big zip/tgz) and pipe it to the sendmail command instead of the other way around.